# Не удается прочитать из хранилища

Tags: java, git, github, git-push

Не могу запушить проект на гитхаб.Пользуюсь Intelliji Idea. Получаю такую ошибку: `Failed with error: Could not read from remote repository.`
Пробывал добавлять ssh key в git GUI, но теперь при попытке сделать Push я еще получаю сообщение:`Authentication using key C:\Users\Vlad/.ssh/id_rsa failed.`
Как решить?

При добавлении ssh ключа по [этому](https://habr.com/post/266667/) туториалу получаю следующее сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как был создан локальный репозиторий? Через git init или clone?

Comment: Сначала был создан в студии, а затем share project on GitHub

Comment: судя по ответу Вы имеете слабое представление о чем идет речь. Я спросил как был создан локальный GIT репозиторий, которым Вы пользуетесь. Просто скачали с GitHub ZIP файл и распаковали в директории?

Comment: Нет. Изначально проекта не было на гитхабе. Я создал проект в студии -> затем добавил созданный проект на github(Создал репозиторий)

Comment: Т.е. на GitHub кода еще нет? Там просто пустой репозиторий?

Comment: К сожалению, да

Comment: Уже ситуация проясняется. А оперативная система какая?

Comment: Я использую windows 10

Answer (score 0):

1. Устанавливаем GIT для Windows: https://gitforwindows.org/
2. Открываем консоль и идем в папку с проектом
3. Кофигурируем GIT: email, username, etc. (смотреть документацию)
4. Создаем локальный GIT репозиторий: `git init`
5. Указываем удаленный репозиторий: `git remote add origin https://github.com/link/to/repo` - посмотреть полный линк на странице проекта в GitHub
6. Создаем `.gitignore` и сразу добавляем туда папки и файлы, которые не должны быть в репозитории
7. Добавляем все репозиторий: `git add .`
8. Делаем первый коммит: `git commit -am "My first commit bla bla bla"`
9. Запузыриваем все в удаленный репозиторий: `git push origin master`

Comment: Не получилось. Вот какое сообщение я получил:`$ git push origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Репозиторий публичный? Когда пушили пароль запрашивался?

Comment: Публичный. Пароль не запрашивался

Comment: Тогда думаю Вам сюда https://habr.com/post/266667/ Скорее всего нужно переустановить SSH ключи или еще что в этом роде

Comment: Мне это не помогает я получаю сообщение которое добавил в свой вопрос.